# Is there a simple way to use python3.10+ structural pattern matching to match a value to a dict by items?

Tags: python, pattern-matching, python-3.10

I have a function that accepts a `dict` of a single item with `str` key and `float` value and I want to check if it has a correct format before returning a tuple of the item. As long as it's not possible to write something like `case {str(k): float(v)}` I've expected that a code with unpacking `dict` with syntax as in it's positional constructor with `MutableMapping` would work, but it does nothing:

```
def test(dct: dict[str, float]) -> tuple[str, float]:
    match dct:
        case dict([(str(k), float(v))]):
            return k, v
        case 
            raise ValueError()
```

I tried different implementation of this pattern matching which looks not as simple as I want. Some of most approaching are:

- using additional check for the type of `dct` before entering pattern matching and passing `None` value if it's not a dict

```
def test(dct: dict[str, float]) -> tuple[str, float]:
    match list(dct.items()) if isinstance(dct, dict) else None:
        case [(str(k), float(v))]:
            return k, v
        case _:
            raise ValueError()
```

- using nested pattern matching after the type is checked by the outer one

```
def test(dct: dict[str, float]) -> tuple[str, float]:
    match dct:
        case d if isinstance(d, dict):
            match list(d.items()):
                case [(str(k), float(v))]:
                    return k, v
            raise ValueError()
        case _:
            raise TypeError("Expected a dictionary")
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you use `isinstance` directly so no need for match-case:

```
def test(dct):
    if not isinstance(dct, dict):
        return ValueError
    k = list(dct.keys())[0]
    v = dct[k]
    if isinstance(k, str) and isinstance(v, float):
        return k, v
    else:
        return ValueError
```